# How to have multiple clocks on one page?

Tags: javascript

I have a working **javascript** code but I want to have more than one clock on a single page.
For example i need 3 clocks. 
I can't figure it out how to have multiple ids in `getelementbyid`?

```
<div id="time">October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)</div>



var timestamp = document.getElementById('time'),
t         = new Date(timestamp.innerHTML),
hours     = t.getHours(), 
min       = t.getMinutes() + '', 

months    = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

if(min.length == 1) min = '0' + min;
timestamp.innerHTML =  hours + ':' + min ;
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you cannot have multiple of them. You can use a class name. Also, please use 'JavaScript' not 'Java' when referring to JavaScript; Java is a different language.

Comment: getElementById can only select one element at a time. So you'd have to repeat that command 3 times and operate separately on each selected element. If you want to get cleverer then give all your clock elements the same CSS class, and use querySelector() to select them all and apply the same code to each one in turn. You can find examples of this kind of thing quite easily online.

Comment: can you code it Sir with css class and querySelector() ?

Comment: I'll repeat..."You can find examples of this kind of thing quite easily online.". Try something. If you get stuck part way through, ask us again. You learn much better by doing. There's not much need for us to re-invent the wheel, IMHO.

Comment: I search all day and have e headache. I am not good with java. I want this time format Oct 21, 2018 19:00:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)  simly to be shown as 18:00 on my site because it will show as 19:00 if user is in other time zone for example

Comment: "I'm not good with java".  Well that's ok because this is JavaScript. So your ability with Java is not really relevant. As for the date format, that sounds like a separate question, it's certainly nothing directly related to having 3 clocks on the page. Try to keep to one issue at a time.

Comment: anyway I figure it out !

Comment: @viper1 That's great...in that case please post as an Answer for everyone to learn from (and potentially give you upvotes). Although now B Cratty has corrected their answer I think that is also giving you the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here is on the right answer, I just thought it would help if maybe you saw some code to reference what they were saying

```js
var timestamp1 = document.getElementById('time1')
getTime(timestamp1)
var timestamp2 = document.getElementById('time2')
getTime(timestamp2)
var timestamp3 = document.getElementById('time3')
getTime(timestamp3)

    function getTime(obj){
        t = new Date(obj.innerHTML),
        hours = t.getHours(), 
        min = t.getMinutes() + '', 
       
        months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

        if(min.length == 1){
             min = '0' + min;
         }

        obj.innerHTML =  hours + ':' + min;
    }
```

```html
<div id="time1">October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)</div>
<div id="time2">October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)</div>
<div id="time3">October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)</div>
```

Please let me know if this was helpful! Thank you!

Comment: no Sir, it is shown as this now: October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)  instead the correct 18:00

Comment: I just updated my answer let me know if this works for you @viper1

Comment: It is giving me a the unexpected token var, which menas Im probably missing some bracket or parenthese

Comment: same incorrect format as a result: October 25, 2018 18:00 GMT+0300 (CDT)

Comment: What about now? @viper1 The reason it wasnt formatting properly is because I never changed the ID name of the HTML element.

Comment: not working and doesn't want to show 18:00 which is the correct format

Comment: "which menas Im probably missing some bracket or parenthese"...no, it means that `getTime(var obj)` is invalid syntax. You can't specify the type in a method signature in JavaScript. Remove the `var` and then your code snippet will actually execute, and as far as I can see, it will show the right time.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, I just changed the snippet per your comment